# Showing "Disable Adblock" image under ad

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make it so that if you have adblock enabled an image will show behind the ad banner on my website which says "**Please consider disabling adblock**".

How ever it just shows up as a box with border.

[This is the box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7b5j.jpg)

Here is my code.

```
.banner {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding: 5px 0px;
width: 750px;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
height: 90x;
min-height: 90px;
/* Disable Adblock Banner. */
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/dUEUcJY.png");
border: 1px solid #191919;
```

}

And here is my HTML.

```
<div class="banner">
  <center>

    <!-- Some Ad Content Here -->

  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: A note, [center is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

Comment: @Vucko I did not know that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use JavaScript to achieve this.

```
<script>



$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout("checkAds();", 1000);

});



function checkAds() {

    if ($(".adsense").height() == "0") {

            $(".adsense").after("<div style='text-align: center; padding:     10px;'>Looks like you've enabled <strong>AdBlock</strong>. It's cool, we get it. Ads can be annoying for sure, but they help keep the free music flowing.</div>");

    }

}

</script>
```

Then wrap your ads with `<div class="adsense"></div>` change this to what ever you want

Answer (score 3):

Try using this CSS instead :

```css
.banner {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  width: 750px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 90x;
  min-height: 90px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/dUEUcJY.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```